# How to log Digester with Apache Commons?

Tags: java, logging, apache-commons-logging

I'm having trouble getting Apache Commons [Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/) to log anything. I'd be hugely grateful for any light anyone can shed.

In my code I'm doing this:

```
Digester digester = new Digester();
// some Digester set up stuff

// What on earth should go in here????
digester.setLogger(LogFactory.getLog("org.apache.commons.logging.Log"));
```

I have a `commons-logging.properties` file in my classpath as follows:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog
org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.digester.Digester=debug
org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax=info
```

I just get no debug info at all.

Thanks for your help!

*Update*:
Thanks for the answer bwawok - that's what the problem was.
In the [docs for Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/commons-digester-2.0/docs/api/org/apache/commons/digester/package-summary.html#doc.Logging), they suggest that you can just enable the `SimpleLog` of commons-logging. Unfortunately, the `Digester` doesn't appear to output any INFO messages, only DEBUG, and at least on eclipse, `SimpleLog` doesn't output DEBUG messages at all! The result was no INFO messages (because `Digester` sends none) and no DEBUG messages (because `SimpleLog` doesn't forward them!) Once I switched to log4j, all the debug messages came spewing out! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you don't use commons logging. It has some problems, such as not playing nicely with Tomcat 5.5 and higher.

If you are writing your own application (not a library), I suggest you code directly to Log4j. Read a tutorial at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html .  You will have a log4j.properties file like so

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Then in your application you would use

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClassName.class);
logger.info("Doing something I want to log at info... " );
logger.warn("Danger!");
```

If instead you are writing a library to distribute (what most people used commons logging for back in the day), look into sl4j. http://www.slf4j.org/ . Most libraries are switching to this instead of commons logging.